Upgrade from wildfly 13 to 34 version using JDK 8
In wildfly 13 the JDK 8 application are running fine but while trying to upgrade from wildfly 13 to 34. I am getting below error.
12:10:05,194 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.cfrt-fde-3.0.jar".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.cfrt-fde-3.0.jar".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.cfrt-fde-3.0.jar
        at org.jboss.as.server@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:100)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1617)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1580)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: cfrt.lib
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1304)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1660)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1688)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:303)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:287)
        at org.jboss.as.server@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:77)
        ... 8 more

12:10:05,194 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.fms-entity.jar".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.fms-entity.jar".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.fms-entity.jar
        at org.jboss.as.server@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:100)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1617)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1580)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.5.5.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1438)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.findModule(LocalModuleFinder.java:200)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule0(ModuleLoader.java:700)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:693)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:503)
        at org.jboss.modules.DelegatingModuleLoader.preloadModule(DelegatingModuleLoader.java:57)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadExportedModule(ModuleLoader.java:418)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:444)
        at org.jboss.as.server@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ServiceModuleLoader.preloadModule(ServiceModuleLoader.java:127)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1290)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1660)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1688)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:303)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:287)
        at org.jboss.as.server@26.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:77)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.initDataOffset(ZipFile.java:1010)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:478)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:159)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill(Manifest.java:494)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:403)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:462)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:380)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:230)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:80)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:72)
        at org.jboss.modules.VersionDetection.detectVersion(VersionDetection.java:44)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResourceRoot(ModuleXmlParser.java:1124)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseResources(ModuleXmlParser.java:931)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:696)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:334)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:292)
        at org.jboss.modules.xml.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:253)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.parseModuleXmlFile(LocalModuleFinder.java:250)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.lambda$findModule$1(LocalModuleFinder.java:195)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:688)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.findModule(LocalModuleFinder.java:195)
        ... 21 more

12:10:05,286 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "cfrt-fde-3.0.jar")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.cfrt-fde-3.0.jar\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.cfrt-fde-3.0.jar
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: cfrt.lib"}}
12:10:05,301 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "fms-entity.jar")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fms-entity.jar\".main" => "WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.fms-entity.jar
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)"}}

Note :- My application is develop in JDK 8. I don't want to upgrade my JDK.
My expectation is to run application on wildfly 34 without upgrading JDK.

You must upgrade your JDK to at least JDK11 as that is the minimal version required by WIldfly 34. They even suggest to at least use JDK21 for safety and support reasons.

Ok Also I compiled with JDK 11 but still getting same error.


My expectation is to run application on wildfly 34 without upgrading JDK.

Your expectation is unrealistic.
Java 8 not supported in Wildfly 34
Read the documentation before attempting an upgrade.
The release notes for Wildfly 34 clearly state that it runs on Java 11, 17, and 21. The documentation also recommends generally running on the latest LTS (21), where they focus their testing. And they mention that 34 is the last release for Java 11, with 35 supporting only Java 17 & 21.

Our recommendation is that you run WildFly 34 on Java SE 21, as that is the latest LTS JDK release where we have completed the full set of testing we like to do before recommending a particular SE version. WildFly 34 also is heavily tested and runs well on Java 17 and Java 11.

Furthermore, you will be upgrading from Java EE 7 to Jakarta EE 10. That means many changes, with more release notes you should be studying before you attempt an upgrade. The changes include the package name change from javax.* to jakarta.*.
Java 8 supported in WildFly 26.1.3.Final
The last release of Wildfly supporting Java 8 is WildFly 26.1.3.Final.
So noted in the Release Notes for 26.1.0 and for 27.0.0.
You’ll only be jumping from Java EE 7 to Java EE 8/Jakarta EE 8.
I do not know if Wildfly 26.1.3 is supported publicly. The Release Notes seem to suggest not. If you are truly limited to Java 8, you may want to consider purchasing a support plan from Red Hat for the equivalent version of their JBoss software.

You should upgrade to WildFly 26.1.3.Final which is the latest version supporting JavaEE and JDK8.

@ehsavoie I added your info. Thanks.

Ok Also I compiled with JDK 11 but still getting same error.
